# Display content if variable is not empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I think I'm getting closer, but it's not working. Thank you so much for taking a look!

This works: On the form (index.html) when user selects 'include' radio the content is shown on the form then on welcome.php after submit. It's hidden from both otherwise.

The problem: I would like to do the same and hide the content on welcome.php when submitted if no value is entered on animalvillas1, animalvillas2 & animalvillas3 independantly.

Please see index.html & welcome.php below:

index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='animalvillas']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes1").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<form name="create" action="welcome.php" method="post">
<span><strong>Lodge Villas - Jambo</strong></span><BR />
<label for="chkYes1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="animalvillas" value="Y" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="animalvillas" value="N" checked />
    Exclude
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvanimalvillas" style="display: none">
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas1" size="3" /> - Value Studio - Standard View (Parking View) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas2" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Standard View (Water / Pool) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas3" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

welcome.php

```
    <div id="dvanimalvillas" <?php echo ($_POST['animalvillas'] == "N") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; ?>>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas1)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas1"]; ?> - Value Studio - Standard View <BR><?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas2)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas2"]; ?> - Deluxe Studio - Standard View <BR><?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas3)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas3"]; ?> - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <BR><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, sorry, I pulled this snippet out to show here, forgot to take that out

Comment: go with if(isset($_POST['yourvar']) ....

Comment: Thanks Lemmy. I used this, but the line is still showing if value is left blank.

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['animalvillas1'])) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas1"]; ?> - Value Studio - Standard View <BR><?php } ?>

Comment: dumb question, have you echo $animalvillas1/2/3 ? what value is shown?

Comment: anyway look here for docs https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: yes. when I echo it shows whatever the value user places in the index.html

Comment: yes, I read that and thought it was right, but it's still showing when nothing is entered into that field

Comment: check additionally for empty String. (if ($_POST['animalvillas1'] != '')). This is valid. Depends. If it is a Form value, it might be transfered as empty value. Not exactly sure how this behaves by default, assume it is an empty value in your case. so combination of isset and isempty will probably do

Comment: In your case isset does nothing, as you only check for keys you know exist in the view ...

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
<div id="dvanimalvillas"  <?php echo ($_POST['animalvillas'] == "N") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; ?>>
    <?php 
        $animalvillas1 = $_POST["animalvilas1"];
        $animalvillas2 = $_POST["animalvilas2"];
        $animalvillas3 = $_POST["animalvilas3"];

        if(!empty($animalvillas1)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas1"]." - Value Studio - Standard View <BR>";
        }
        if(!empty($animalvillas2)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas2"]." - Deluxe Studio - Standard View <BR>";
        }
        if(!empty($animalvillas3)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas3"]." - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <BR>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This will print your full line if variables have value otherwise not.

Check it 
[index.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppnubump5dskwpg/index.php?dl=0) 
[welcome.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvay32j931k05yo/welcome.php?dl=0)

Comment: Ok, I have edited this and tried myself as you told, now it is working well.

Comment: Can you please verify. I have copy/pasted/uploaded/tried your edited code multiple times and anything I submit, welcome.php comes up blank

Comment: I have placed a dropbox link to those file which i write. you can check your self. check to see if it help or let me know.

Comment: Hemant, thank you, but this has taken out the functionality of the radio selection for the main section

Comment: Yes, i have not included the radio button but when you apply them that will work, this is code for going to next page and show/hide lines

Comment: When I try to apply the radio button, it does not work and comes blank on welcome.php

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o5qqbbskupeu43/index.php?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkracn9nfbsk6qa/welcome.php?dl=0

Comment: i tried it and it is working. see result

https://s32.postimg.org/4c2e727ed/index.png
https://s32.postimg.org/pmzybbpit/welcome.png